# Pricing criteria of AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am confused about pricking criteria in aws s3.

Let's assume

SELECT * FROM TABLE => result 1000 rows

Is this command 1000 requests or 1 request?

Comment: Are you asking for Athena Query pricing?

Comment: How are you running this query?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
I am using amplify

Comment: Then please put that information into your question, together with information that can help people understand your situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sorry about that..

Answer (score 2):

If you using S3 Select to query, it is a single request and you get charged for every 1000 requests and charged at the same rate as object GET requests

If you are using Athena to query S3, the charge would be for the amount of data retrieved and how the file is stored like zip or parquet format

Comment: I am using amplify

Comment: You mean, 
List<Object> a = Amplify.DataStore.query(where: id.eq('123'));
=> 1 SELECT and 1000 GET ??
// a.length = 1000

Comment: There is no additional charges to use Amplify DataStore in your Amplify application, you only pay for the backend resources you use, such as AppSync and DynamoDB. Refer to their pricing details

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 Select charges for the bytes scanned ($0.00200 per GB) and the bytes returned ($0.0007 per GB).

The charges are broken in your billing management console Under Billing>Bills>Details>Simple Storage Service>Region> "Amazon Simple Storage Service USE2-Select-Returned-Bytes" and "Amazon Simple Storage Service USE2-Select-Scanned-Bytes"

Using limit, where clauses or having a compressed file reduces the bytes scanned. The service supports gzipped Parquet files which is fantastic. I was able to reduce file sizes by 90% and take advantage of columnar data format rather than csv.